# Upload image to iis server and display on client

Tags: windows-runtime, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I have table PRODUCT(Id, Name, ImagePath) in database.
In WINRT client user can insert product with image in their folder and send by POST method.

```
try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var reader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
            var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            reader.ReadBytes(bytes);

            HttpContent httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.51.115:9696/api/MediaUpload/UploadMediaFile?fileName=}" + fileName, httpContent);
            HttpResponseMessage message = response;

            if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Status.Text = "Upload completed";
            }
            else
            {
                Status.Text = message.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status.Text = ex.Message + " Error";
        }
```

In server will received image byte array and store in local folder.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadMediaFile(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            string path = ??? // What is path???

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

            ms.WriteTo(fs);

            ms.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            return Ok(path);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

then get path to display image on client like

```
<Image Height="300"
       Width="300"
       Source="http://192.168.51.115:9696/FileUpload/image.png"/>
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: yes. string path = ??? // What is path???